# Запуск webview при смене activity

Tags: android, activity, android-layout, webview

День добрый. 
У меня есть простой проект состоящий из 2х activity. Главное - в котором запрашивается url, и второе - webview. Дело в том, что webview пытается загрузить приложение до того, как задастся url в главном(через стринг). Как заставить webview начать грузить url только тогда, когда его activity станет активным?

Comment: Вы что-то путаете - вторая активность не может ничего делать до тех пор пока Вы сами её не запустите - стало-быть Вы неправильно организуете своё приложение.      
Но из вопроса ничего не понять - нужны подробности

Comment: код в студию! Мой ясновидящий сегодня отпросился "за свой счет", так что угадать сегодня я не могу...((

Comment: > Дело в том, что webview пытается загрузить приложение

вот здесь какая то заковырка. какое приложение оно пытается загрузить?